# Variance of PDF - correct integral setup?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, variance

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with PDF,

$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} {ke^{-2x}} & \text{$x > 0$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

a) Find $k$.

b) Find the mean of $X$.

c) Find the variance of $X$.

c) Find the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) of $X$.

---

a) $k = 2$. No problems there.

b) I am getting $E(X) = \frac{1}{2}$.

c) This is where things get a little crazy. Is it me or is the integral required to find the variance a little complex?

$\int_{0}^\infty (x - \frac{1}{2})^2 \ (2e^{-2x}) \ dx$

I'm struggling to evaluate this! Is this the correct integral?

---

**edit:**: It all came to me and I solved it ($var(X) = \frac{1}{4}$). Currently working on part d)...

---

d)

$F(x) = \begin{cases} {0} & \text{$x \leq 0$} \\ {-e^{-2x} + 1} & \text{$x > 0$}\end{cases}$

Comment: Hint: You can calculate $\mathbb E(X^2)=\int_{0}^\infty x ^2 \ (2e^{-2x}) \ dx$. Then use $Var(X)=\mathbb E(X^2)-[\mathbb E(X)]^2$. Have you tried integration by parts ?

Comment: I literally just solved it haha. Working on part d) now!

Comment: Good luck for d). And var(X) is indeed $\frac14$.

Comment: updated the OP at the bottom with my answer for d). thoughts?

Comment: It looks right to me. $1-e^{-2x}$ would look better to me.

Comment: (1) I can confirm that your answer to (d) looks correct!
(2) Here's how you can confirm that for yourself in the future: if you're trying to check that you've correctly obtained $F(x)$ from $f(x)$, check that it's continuous, has the correct limits as $x \to \pm \infty$, and that its derivative is indeed $f(x)$.